# Async ContentProvider

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider

I have an special image format that must be processed for a thumbnail before it is displayed.  I have a solid disk cache/mem cache/asynctask framework in place.  I want to migrate to using ContentProviders with the ability to process that thumbnail asynchronously.

Now most examples involve a single query loading data (network, etc.) in the background with a CursorAdapter listening for a change, but ideally I would not process the thumbnail until a UI element requests it, not just when the initial data set is queried.  For example, if there are far more images than the screen will display.

Update:

[Deleted no longer relevant data]

Digging through the whole ContentResolver/Provider process I've concluded that ContentProvider.openfile is the answer and a ContentProvider should only provide a disk cache since streams would be a real PIA.  This makes some sense anyway, since I'm willing to bet the overhead accessing the ContentResolver would defeat some of the purpose of maintaining the memory cache.

So the client will check the memory cache and fallback on calling a ContentResolver which would check its own disk cache and if needed process the file.

1. Is a long-running process in ContentProvider.opeFile an issue?
2. If it is can I pass a temp file out and notify the resolver when the
   file is actually ready?
3. If so would this process be something another app could handle in a
   share intent, etc.?
4. Does this make sense to begin with :/ ?